# Exception raised: read access violation. std :: shared_ptr <Weapon> :: operator -> <Weapon, 0> (...) returned nullptr., happened

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

**PROBLEM**

Exception occurs during program startup and during debugging.  Exceptions occur when retrieving data using the get ???? () methods;  Weapon class.  The exception looks like this:
 An exception occurred: violation of reading rights.  std :: shared_ptr :: operator -> (...) returned nullptr.  The code in Hero.h comments out the problem fragments, method calls.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Hero.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

Hero* GetSomeHero()
{
    switch (1 + rand() % 5)
    {
    case 1: return new Human(100);
    case 2: return new King(300);
    case 3: return new Queen(150);
    case 4: return new Knight(200);
    case 5: return new Troll(250);
    }
    return new Human(100);
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    std::shared_ptr<Hero> hero(GetSomeHero());
    std::shared_ptr<Hero> enemy(GetSomeHero());


    while (true)
    {
        hero->attackOutput(*enemy);
        enemy->attackOutput(*hero);

        if (hero->isDead())
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Hero> temp(GetSomeHero());
            hero.swap(temp);
        }
        if (enemy->isDead())
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Hero> temp(GetSomeHero());
            enemy.swap(temp);
        }

        std::cout << *hero << std::endl << *enemy << std::endl;
        Sleep(200);
        system("cls");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Weapon.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Weapon
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    float damage;
    int wear;
public:
    Weapon(std::string name, float damage, int wear)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->damage = damage;
        this->wear = wear;
    }
    virtual void setWear(int wear) = 0;
    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
    virtual float getDamage() = 0;
    virtual int getWear() = 0;
};

class Fist : public Weapon // KULAK
{
protected:
public:
    Fist() : Weapon("Fist", 1, 3) {}
    virtual void setWear(int wear)
    {
        this->wear = wear;
    }
    virtual std::string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    virtual float getDamage()
    {
        return this->damage;
    }
    virtual int getWear()
    {
        return this->wear;
    }
};

class Knife : public Weapon // NOZH
{
protected:
public:
    Knife() : Weapon("Knife", 5, 5) {}
    virtual void setWear(int wear)
    {
        this->wear = wear;
    }
    virtual std::string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    virtual float getDamage()
    {
        return this->damage;
    }
    virtual int getWear()
    {
        return this->wear;
    }
};

class Bow : public Weapon // LUCK
{
protected:
public:
    Bow() : Weapon("Bow", 15, 10) {}
    virtual void setWear(int wear)
    {
        this->wear = wear;
    }
    virtual std::string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    virtual float getDamage()
    {
        return this->damage;
    }
    virtual int getWear()
    {
        return this->wear;
    }
};

class Ax : public Weapon // TOPOR
{
protected:
public:
    Ax() : Weapon("Ax", 30, 5) {}
    virtual void setWear(int wear)
    {
        this->wear = wear;
    }
    virtual std::string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    virtual float getDamage() 
    {
        return this->damage;
    }
    virtual int getWear()
    {
        return this->wear;
    }
};

class Sword : public Weapon // MECH
{
protected:
public:
    Sword() : Weapon("Sword", 25, 8) {}
    virtual void setWear(int wear)
    {
        this->wear = wear;
    }
    virtual std::string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    virtual float getDamage()
    {
        return this->damage;
    }
    virtual int getWear()
    {
        return this->wear;
    }
};
```

**Hero.h**

```
#include "Weapon.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

class Hero
{
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Weapon> weapon;
    std::string name;
    float health;
    int pressure;
    int beauty;
    int skill;
    int horror;
public:
    Hero(std::string name, float health, int pressure, int beauty, int skill, int horror)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->health = health;
        this->pressure = 1 + rand() % pressure;;
        this->beauty = 1 + rand() % beauty;
        this->skill = 1 + rand() % skill;
        this->horror = 1 + rand() % horror;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Hero& obj)
    {
        os << std::endl
            << obj.name << std::endl
            << "Health: " << obj.health << std::endl
            /*<< "Weapon: " << obj.weapon->getName() << "[" << obj.weapon->getDamage() << "]\n"*/
            << "Specifications:\n"
            << "Pressure[" << obj.pressure << "], Beauty[" << obj.beauty << "], Skill[" << obj.skill << "], Horror[" << obj.pressure << "]\n";
        return os;
    }
    bool isDead()
    {
        if (this->health > 0) return false;
        else return true;
    }
    virtual void weaponСhange() = 0;
    virtual void attackOutput(Hero& enemy) = 0;
    virtual void attackInput(int damage) = 0;
};

class Human : public Hero
{
protected:
public:
    Human(float health) : Hero("Human", health, 1, 1, 1, 1) {}
    virtual void weaponСhange()
    {
        weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Fist);
    }
    virtual void attackOutput(Hero& enemy)
    {
        /*if (this->weapon->getWear() <= 0) this->weaponСhange();*/
        enemy.attackInput(1 /*+ (int)this->weapon->getDamage()*/);
        /*this->weapon->setWear(this->weapon->getWear() - 1);*/
    }
    virtual void attackInput(int damage)
    {
        this->health -= damage;
    }
};

class King : public Hero
{
protected:
public:
    King(float health) : Hero("King", health, 10, 15, 4, 3) {}
    virtual void weaponСhange()
    {
        switch (1 + rand() % 3)
        {
        case 1: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Fist);
        case 2: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Knife);
        case 3: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Ax);
        case 4: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Sword);
        }
    }
    virtual void attackOutput(Hero& enemy)
    {
        /*if (this->weapon->getWear() <= 0) this->weaponСhange();*/
        enemy.attackInput(1 + this->pressure + this->skill /*+ (int)this->weapon->getDamage()*/);
        /*this->weapon->setWear(this->weapon->getWear() - 1);*/
    }
    virtual void attackInput(int damage)
    {
        this->health -= damage;
    }
};

class Queen : public Hero
{
protected:
public:
    Queen(float health) : Hero("Queen", health, 2, 15, 10, 1) {}
    virtual void weaponСhange()
    {
        /*if (this->weapon->getWear() <= 0) this->weaponСhange();*/
        switch (1 + rand() % 2)
        {
        case 1: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Fist);
        case 2: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Knife);
        case 3: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Bow);
        }
    }
    virtual void attackOutput(Hero& enemy)
    {
        /*if (this->weapon->getWear() <= 0) this->weaponСhange();*/
        enemy.attackInput(1 + this->beauty + this->skill /*+ (int)this->weapon->getDamage()*/);
        /*this->weapon->setWear(this->weapon->getWear() - 1);*/
    }
    virtual void attackInput(int damage)
    {
        this->health -= damage;
    }
};

class Knight : public Hero
{
protected:
public:
    Knight(float health) : Hero("Knight", health, 15, 6, 20, 1) {}
    virtual void weaponСhange()
    {
        /*if (this->weapon->getWear() <= 0) this->weaponСhange();*/
        switch (1 + rand() % 2)
        {
        case 1: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Fist);
        case 2: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Ax);
        case 3: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Sword);
        }
    }
    virtual void attackOutput(Hero& enemy)
    {
        if (weapon->getWear() <= 0) this->weaponСhange();
        enemy.attackInput(1 + this->skill + this->pressure /*+ (int)this->weapon->getDamage()*/);
        /*this->weapon->setWear(this->weapon->getWear() - 1);*/
    }
    virtual void attackInput(int damage)
    {
        this->health -= damage;
    }
};

class Troll : public Hero
{
protected:
public:
    Troll(float health) : Hero("Troll", health, 20, 1, 1, 10) {}
    virtual void weaponСhange()
    {
        /*if (this->weapon->getWear() <= 0) this->weaponСhange();*/
        switch (1 + rand() % 1)
        {
        case 1: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Fist);
        case 2: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Ax);
        }
    }
    virtual void attackOutput(Hero& enemy)
    {
        if (weapon->getWear() <= 0) this->weaponСhange();
        enemy.attackInput(1 + this->horror + this->pressure /*+ (int)this->weapon->getDamage()*/);
        /*this->weapon->setWear(this->weapon->getWear() - 1);*/
    }
    virtual void attackInput(int damage)
    {
        this->health -= damage;
    }
};
```

Comment: 1) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, while investigating the values of all of the variables? 2) Dowvoted just for "_stackoverflow asks for more information, butI can not give more information._" spam. For instance, you could have explained what have you tried to solve the problem on your own. For example: what you noticed when stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: Make a [mcve] and remove the spam.

Comment: I said that an exception occurs.  The same will be logical when debugging.  I slightly changed the description of the problem in the post.  I can’t delete spam.  Otherwise, stackoverflow will not be missed for low content.  And an example has already been given - an exception occurs when calling methods from the Weapon class that are commented out in the code in Hero.h

Comment: "_I can’t delete spam_" - Yes you can. Just click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60041983/edit) and remove it and add a [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem causing the crashes is most probably that you call `weapon->getWear()` in `attackOutput()` for `Knight` and `Troll`. You do this before you've assigned a weapon to them.

Another problem: You haven't made the bases classes destructors `virtual`. This means that the smart pointer will only destroy the base class part of the object when it's time to destroy it.

A third problem: Many of your `switch`es assign variables, but don't `break` so the values will be overwritten over and over again and will finally be assigned the value in the last `case`. In this case, you'll get a random number, `[1, 3]` (not `[1, 4]`), and you'll get a `Sword` every time.

```
        switch (1 + rand() % 3)
        {
        case 1: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Fist);  // missing break;
        case 2: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Knife); // missing break;
        case 3: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Ax);    // missing break;
        case 4: weapon = std::shared_ptr<Weapon>(new Sword); // missing break;
        }
```

Sidenotes:

- Prefer `weapon = std::make_shared<Fist>();` etc. instead of the above.
- Prefer `std::unique_ptr` over `std::shared_ptr` unless you actually need reference counted pointers.
- Pick one type for damage and health etc. You now use a mix of `float` and `int`.
- When you override a member function in a subclass, you can skip the `virtual` specifier (it does not matter) and instead add the [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier. This will make the compiler complain if the function doesn't actually override a virtual function.
- In logical expressions as

  ```
  bool isDead() {
      if (this->health > 0) return false;
      else return true;
  }
  ```

  you already have a boolean result inside the `if(...)` so prefer to return it directly. In this case, you can simply do this instead:

  ```
  bool isDead() {
      return this->health <= 0;
  }
  ```
- Use the `<random>` random number generators and support functions for better randomization. Since you generate a lot of numbers between `1` and some max value (inclusive), you could make a support function for it. Example:

  ```
  #include <random>

  int my_rand(int max) {
      // the generator will only be seeded once since it's static
      static std::mt19937 generator(std::random_device{}());

      std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, max); // range: [1, max]
      return dist(generator);
  }
  ```
- If you have a default implementation for some of the virtual functions, you can implement it in the base class to save youself a lot of copy/pasting. Only override it in those cases you want something special. Example for a few `Weapon`s:

  ```
  class Weapon {
  private:
      // Direct access to member variables is usually not a good idea. Try to keep them
      // private.
      std::string name;
      float damage;
      int wear;
  protected:
      // The constructor can be protected, only subclasses will be able to use it.
      Weapon(std::string Name, float Damage, int Wear) : // use the initializer list
          name(Name), damage(Damage), wear(Wear)
      {}

      // virtual destructor
      virtual ~Weapon() = default;

  public:
      virtual void setWear(int Wear) { wear = Wear; }
      virtual void applyWear() { --wear; }
      virtual const std::string& getName() { return name; }
      virtual float getDamage() const { return damage; }
      virtual int getWear() { return wear; }
  };

  class Fist : public Weapon // KULAK
  {
  public:
      Fist() : Weapon("Fist", 1, 3) {}
  };

  class Knife : public Weapon // NOZH
  {
  public:
      Knife() : Weapon("Knife", 5, 5) {}
  };
  ...
  ```